# Does useQuery and useState fire only on component mount?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

I got kinda puzzled by this behavior today, hopefully you can shed some light on it. Sorry for being lazy to write minimal code version, but it should be easy to follow.

I have a React Component ( its table you fill in and submit it ) which is including another component ( Breadcrumb component ). Breadcrumb has steps after this table step disabled - this is managed by boolean which is returned from GraphQl API, which checks, if the table was filled in.

The problem I was facing was that my GraphQl API was not firing with Breadcrumb component re-render - and - I also passed a prop from TableComponent to Breadcrumb and stored in in useState in BreadCrumb - but - default state did not change.

Why is this? Does GraphQl query and useState update ONLY on component mount, not on each render?

Answer (score 0):

You query is most likely resolved from cache. You have to explicitly use a fetch policy that disables resolving from cache. Relying on rerenders to trigger queries sounds like something you might want to avoid though. Instead, you could use `useEffect` that triggers a [refetch query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/). Your effect could then listen (by listing a dependency as a second parameter) on the values that you actually want to observe. It is likely that your architecture is not quite sound. Another thing I am hearing is you are creating state from props. Again this is something you should avoid unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Why can't your component simply receive a property `tableCompleted`?

Comment: its not the cache - I have 'no-cache' as default setting and even used 'no-cache' as param @ this particular query. I ended up with using exactly useEffect listening to prop ( tableCompleted is the prop ) and calling refetch() - but anyway - I dont understand why I had to. 

Why you mean I should avoid creating state from prop? I know its kinda meh, I was meant to work around this query problem, but the fact, that the state was not stored on render did surprise me. 

Do you know, if hooks fire only on component mount, not render?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with hooks _fire_? Maybe you should really make a repository that shows what you mean. `useState` preserves state over multiple renders and triggers rerenders on change. Use effect triggers, when the dependencies changed. `useRef` can also be used to keep a value across renders.

Comment: fire - gets called

Comment: The only hook that I can vaguely associate _fire_ with is the `useEffect` hook. Is this a general hook concept? Effects are different than lifecyle events: https://dev.to/ijones16/stop-thinking-in-lifecycle-methods-1fjj